# How to detect when json isn't json (it's html)

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing

I'm working with a companies broken API. When the endpoint isn't available I don't hit an error it just sends back page unavailable HTML in the body (normally it returns JSON).

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if the body should be parsed into json or thrown out.

I'm using javascript, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it change its MIME type appropriately?

Comment: Does it return a different status code or headders?

Comment: The response status code should be what you are looking at.  When the API "fails" does it still return 200 OK? Hopefully it gives something like a 500 status instead. Or look at other headers, like mimetype. I bet you can find something better than the content to make the decision of success/fail on.

Comment: @sLaks No, same status code.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes, still returns 200.

Comment: JSON should start with `{` or `[`. It's unlikely that an HTML document would start with those characters

Answer (score 5):

You could just try to parse it and if it fails, it's not valid JSON:

```
function tryParse(jsonstring){
    try{
       return JSON.parse(jsonstring);
    }
    catch(err){
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad. I fixed it.

Comment: The safe way, I just hate try/catches. They can be OK as long as you don't wrap multiple statements (which happens as people add code)

Comment: Well, if you're service is returning 200, there's not much you can do